# Setting up queues in slurm based on resource request

Tags: slurm

I'm curious if there is a way to setup Slurm partitions so that the scheduler will query against available partitions and assign to a partition depending on amount of requested resources, eg. say I have a few queues:

```
small_cpu = node1,2,3          <- assigned when requesting <= 10 cores
large_cpu = node4,5,6          <- assigned when requesting > 10 cores
big_mem = node7,8,9            <- assign when requesting > 100GB memory
fail/backfill = nodes10,11,12  <- assigned when the other queues are full
```

I'm able to do this in PBS/Moab, but I'm having difficulty with the Slurm documentation trying to figure it out. Any insight is appreciated.

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do that exact thing in Slurm is with a job submit plugin that allows you to incorporate any logic in the routing of the jobs to partition (and many more).

See an example [here](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/blob/master/contribs/lua/job_submit.lua).